# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_sparse'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

[`sdf = df.to_sparse()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sparse.html) has been deprecated. What's the updated way to convert to a sparse DataFrame?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ad190575aa75962d2d0eade2de81a5fe5a2e285b/doc/source/whatsnew/v1.0.0.rst#removal-of-prior-version-deprecationschanges

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the [updated sparse conversions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#sparse-migration) in pandas 1.0.0+.

---

### How to convert dense to sparse

Use [`DataFrame.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype) with the appropriate [`SparseDtype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseDtype.html#pandas.SparseDtype) (e.g., `int`):

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]})
>>> df.dtypes
# A    int64
# dtype: object

>>> sdf = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype(int, fill_value=0))
>>> sdf.dtypes
# A    Sparse[int64, 0]
# dtype: object
```

Or use the string alias for brevity:

```
>>> sdf = df.astype('Sparse[int64, 0]')
```

---

### How to convert sparse to dense

Use [`DataFrame.sparse.to_dense()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.to_dense.html):

```py
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> sdf = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(sparse.eye(3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> sdf.dtypes
# A    Sparse[float64, 0]
# B    Sparse[float64, 0]
# C    Sparse[float64, 0]
# dtype: object

>>> df = sdf.sparse.to_dense()
>>> df.dtypes
# A    float64
# B    float64
# C    float64
# dtype: object
```

---

### How to convert sparse to [COO](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)

Use [`DataFrame.sparse.to_coo()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.to_coo.html):

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> sdf = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(sparse.eye(3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> sdf.dtypes
# A    Sparse[float64, 0]
# B    Sparse[float64, 0]
# C    Sparse[float64, 0]
# dtype: object

>>> df = sdf.sparse.to_coo()
# <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#         with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
# (0, 0)    1.0
# (1, 1)    1.0
# (2, 2)    1.0
```

Comment: For converting sparse to dense, it seems there is no error when `scipy` is not imported, is `scipy` needed there?

Comment: @chen If you already have a supported sparse matrix without importing scipy, it's not needed. `scipy.sparse` is only needed here for the sample data `sparse.eye(3)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use scipy to create sparse matrix:

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```